# How to do different wight column in android GridView

Tags: android

I need to do editable table with columns, where one column has width 300dp and other 100dp.
My activity code:

```
ArrayList<String> data =new ArrayList<String> ();
    GridView gvMain;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     public void initList()
        {
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.item3, R.id.editText1, data) 
         {
           @Override
           public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
           {
                 if (convertView == null)
                    {
                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item3, null);
                    }
                    final String theData = getItem(position);
                    final EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    editText.setText(theData);
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(
                            new MyTextWatcher(position)
                    );
                    return convertView;
                }
            };
            gvMain.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.orp);
        data=MyClass.GetData();
        gvMain = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        initList();
    }
}
```

Now EditText width depend on text, but gridview column width the same. How to set different size for different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find solution and used ten different GridView with different width.